# Fitting TikZ graphs into a small space

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am trying to produce a graph of the kind at the end of Kanamori's textbook - "The Higher Infinite":

[image: Large Cardinal diagram]

It would be nice to have a method that extends to any graph of implications, so rather than put everything in manually, I was looking at the PGF `graphdrawing` library. This is a very useful tool, but I am producing this diagram for a presentation using `beamer`, and the output doesn't readily fit on a slide. Shrinking it would make it a bit unreadable, so I was trying other tricks.

Here's what I've got (uses graphdrawing, so needs `LuaTeX` and `PGF 3.0`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\Tiny}{\tiny}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force, layered, trees}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum size=5mm}]
        \graph [layered layout, minimum layers=1, grow=down, level distance=5mm, sibling distance=1cm] {
            { [same layer] 0=1 -> "I0-I3" -> "n-huge" } ->
            { [same layer] superhuge -> huge -> "almost huge" } ->
            { "Vopenka's Principle" -> [second] extendible } ->
            supercompact -> {strongly compact, superstrong} ->
            { [same layer] Woodin -> strong -> "$0^\dagger$" exists } ->
            measurable ->
            { [same layer] Ramsey -> Rowbottom -> "J\'onsson" } ->
            "$0^\sharp$ exists" ->
            { [same layer] indescribable -> weakly compact -> Mahlo} ->
            inaccessible ->
            ZFC
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum size=5mm}]
        \graph [layered layout, minimum layers=1, grow=down, level distance=5mm, sibling distance=1cm] {
            { [same layer] 0=1 -> "I0-I3" -> "n-huge" } ->
            { [same layer] superhuge -> huge -> "almost huge" } ->
            { "Vopenka's Principle" -> [second] extendible } ->
            supercompact -> {strongly compact, superstrong} ->
            { [same layer] Woodin -> strong -> "$0^\dagger$" exists } ->
            measurable ->
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The first frame shows best what's going wrong, the second shows that it has potential.

[image: Bad]
[image: OK]

The issue is clear: I don't know how to change the direction things in the same layer appear in. I tried to use the `desired at` key to line things up, but this seems to make the algorithm go haywire.

Seeing any kind of solution would be good since I know so little about the library. But in particular I'd like to keep it fairly geometric and regular, which so far I wasn't able to get with the `spring layout`, never mind keep it on the page.